# Checkout SVN externals to the root of the current WC

Tags: svn, externals

I'm trying to checkout a external repository to my current working copy.
This is my setup:
Current Working Copy

> D:\working_copy\

External Path

> D:\external_working_copy\uploads

Then I setup the svn:external property to D:\working_copy\:

> uploads file:///D:/SVN/external_working_copy/trunk/uploads

then if I run update on D:\working_copy\ I got the following:

> D:\working_copy\uploads

but I want the content of file:///D:/SVN/external_working_copy/trunk/uploads to go to the root of D:\working_copy\ and not create uploads inside D:\working_copy.

I have tried to set as

> / file:///D:/SVN/external_working_copy/trunk/uploads

but everything I got is:

> Invalid svn:externals property on 'D:\working_copy': target '/' is an absolute path or involves '..'

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2):

You can't do this, for an obvious reason. How would it decided when you add a new file if it should go in one repository or the other? If you want to point the root of your working copy to the other location, you can just checkout the other location instead?

Comment: > How would it decided when you add a new file if it should go in one repository or the other? -- Actually I develop plugins to a main project. thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try using `.` or `./` as the local path in the external definition. Even then though, I dont think it will work.